# Would it be better with try except imbricated?

Tags: python-3.x

What do you think of this code?  I want to keep an unified interface (treat filepath or image interchangeably) but i have heard try except is the prefered way, how would you do?

```
def rotate_img(imageref, deg):
"""
Rotate from [deg] degree the input image
param imageref: can be imagepath or ndarray image
param deg: number of rotation degree desired
"""
if isinstance(imageref,np.ndarray):
    from scipy import ndimage
    img = imageref
    img_rt = ndimage.rotate(img, deg, reshape=False)
elif isinstance(imageref,str): 
    img = Image.open(imageref)
    img_rt = img.rotate(deg, expand=1)
else:
    raise('Unknown Type')
return img_rt
```

Comment: Welcome to code review. Please note that you need to post your **full working code** for us to review it. Also, [edit] your question so that the title states what your code does. For more information, please read [ask]. As it is now, your question requires more details